# Why is this giving me an error? And how can I fix it (context error)

Tags: flutter

I used this code line elsewhere but it does not give an error

```
AutoSizeText(
        "عنوان"
        ,maxLines: 1
        ,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        minFontSize: 10,
        style:GoogleFonts.rubik(fontSize: 25,color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
      ),
```

[image: Picture 1]
[image]

Comment: before use context, you must be pass context

Comment: I'm assuming that the `generateItem` is a static function (not part of a class). Create a `StatelessWidget` for that to have a `context`.

Comment: you can give me full source code, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extracted widget `generateItem()` outside the state class, `_picturesState`.

So you have to pass the `context` of that state class as an argument of the `generateItem()`. Then you are allowed to use that context inside of `Theme.of(context)`.

Your final solution is:

```
Card generateItem(BuildContext context) {
  return Card(
    //..
  );
}
```

And when you call this widget, simply pass context as an argument like:

```
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children:[
      generateItem(context);
    ]
  )
);
```

This should be inside of your state class which has its own context.